# Map unit ball to lower dim space

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Let $B^n$ be the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $M$ a $m\times n$ matrix with $m<n$ defining a linear map $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$. I would like to characterize the image of $B^n$ under $f$.

My guess is that it is an ellipsoid. I would like to derive explicitly, if possible, an $m\times m$ matrix $P$ such that
$$ f(B^n)=\{y=Px \, ; \, x \in B^m \} $$
for some $k\geq 0$. That is, $P$ defines a linear map $g$ such that the sets $f(B^n)$ and $g(B^m)$ are the same.

If not possible, how to derive $P$ such that $f(B^n) \subset g(B^m)$ in some minimal sense ?

Any idea how to this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition), there exist two orthogonal bases of $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbb R^m$ with respect to which the matrix of $f$ is a rectangular diagonal matrix with nonnegative diagonal entries. Since unit balls are invariant under orthogonal transformations, it is clear that the image of the unit ball under $f$ is an ellipsoid.

Comment: Thank your for the answer. I am not familiar with SVD, can it also be used to derive the matrix $P$ mentioned above ?

Comment: @user149575 Suppose the matrix of $f$ with respect to the standard bases of the two Euclidean spaces be $A$. SVD simply says that $A=U(S,0_{m\times(n-m)})V^T$ for some $m\times m$ orthogonal matrix $U$, $n\times n$ orthogonal matrix $V$ and some $m\times m$ nonnegative diagonal matrix $S=\operatorname{diag}(s_1,s_2,\ldots,s_m)$. It follows that $f(B^n)=U(S,0)V^TB^n=U(S,0)B^n=\{USx: x\in\mathbb{R}^m,\ \|x\|_2\le1\}$. So your $P$ is $US$, if I understand your symbols correctly.

Comment: I see. Many thanks again.